# Shared Hosting Laravel 8 Hosting problem: Symlink is not working

Tags: laravel, web-hosting, symlink, shared-hosting, laravel-8

I need the deploy my laravel project to the web. With this [introduction](https://welcm.uk/blog/putting-a-laravel-app-into-production) But the hosting provider is Doesn't allow me to use a symbolic link(symlink), I called customer service, and told me blocked for security reasons.
So, since I do not use symbolic links, there are big problems in uploading images and deploying them.

Is there a way to do deployment my app?

Comment: create symlink with route

Comment: The hosting provider not allowed the symlink, so please read the question.

Comment: create a custom file system with will upload file in public folder and set default

Answer (score 0):

Change your disk configurations in the `config/filesystems.php` to read and write to public folder via `public_path()` function.

If you're deploying over a shared host, you probably have another folder like `public_html` as your public folder which is not included in your source. Try to link to the *public_html* using dots `../../public_html/`

```
'public' => [
     'driver'     => 'local',
//   'root'       => storage_path('app/public'),
     'root'       => public_path(),
     'url'        => env('APP_URL'),
     'visibility' => 'public',
],
'photos' => [
     'driver'     => 'local',
     'root'       => public_path('photos'),
     'url'        => env('APP_URL') . '/photos',
     'visibility' => 'public',
],
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is just create something like symlink using php, example you can create a route like below:

```
Route::get(
    '/storage/{file}',
    function ($file) {
        $filepath = "../storage/app/public/".$file;

        header("Cache-Control: public");
        header("Content-Type: ".mime_content_type($filepath));
        header('Content-Length: '.filesize($filepath));

        readfile($filepath);
        die();
    }
);
```

Maybe not best practice, but it will solve your problem. It's will do same as symlink.